# Which article to use: 'the' or 'a'

Tags: word-choice, articles, sentence-choice

> 1. We adopt **the** approach under which the ...
> 2. We adopt **an** approach under which the ...
> 3. We consider **the** scenario where ...
> 4. We consider **a** scenario where ...

Suppose that I say nothing about the approach or the scenario before there corresponding sentences. However, suppose that the scenario is known in the literature.

I am a bit confused about the article usage here since I am explaining/clarifying things about the *approach* (resp. *scenario*) after *under which* (resp. after *where*)

Question: (a) which one between 1 and 2 is correct ? 
          (b) which one between 3 and 4 is correct ?

Comment: RE: _Suppose that I say nothing about the approach or the scenario before there_ [_sic_] _corresponding sentences. However, suppose that the scenario is known in the literature._ Your hunch is right – you can use the definite article when referring to something that is specific and well-known (e.g., _There are many ways we could have sorted the data; we decided to use **the** quicksort algorithm_).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you understand that the definite article is used when you are talking about a *specific* case, and the indefinite article used when talking about a *non-specific* or *general* case.  Here, however, since you're introducing something new, both mean almost exactly the same thing.  There is only a slight different in nuance, implying specific or non-specific, but the essential meaning is unchanged either way.

Depending on context, "the" is slightly more confident and assertive, than "a/an".  "The" is more common in things like advertising because it implies that the service or product is *the* specific one you will need:

> We have created **the** website that will answer all your English-language questions
>
> We have created **a** website that will answer all your English-language questions.

It's not always appropriate to be *too* assertive, especially with things like scientific or technical papers where many approaches are possible.  In your example, "the" is appropriate to draw focus to this one, specific approach.  "A" suggests that you might talk about other approaches later, or that you want to imply the approach is *generic*.  Again, both mean much the same thing and any additional meaning will depend on context.

If you add any modifiers to the noun, usually one or the other will work better, but this varies:

> We determined **the** *best* approach where ...
>
> We defined **a** *new* approach where ...